# Set IDENTITY_INSERT OFF for all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script which creates an entire database and inserts all records to a few dozen tables.
It works great, unless there is some issue during the processing, and a table gets left with IDENTITY_INSERT ON, when the script fails during insertion and before it can be set to OFF again.

When this happens, the script automatically fails when attempting to run it again, with the error "IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table xx" as we go into the insertion for the first table.

As a failsafe I would like to make sure that IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF for all tables, before running the rest of the processing in the setup script.

As an alternative, we could perhaps close the MS SQL connection and open it again, which, as I understand it, would clear all IDENTITY_INSERT values for the connection session.

What's the best way to do this, and prevent the "already on" errors?

Comment: This app needs to work w/ 2005 and above, so ideally a solution that works for all recent and upcoming versions.

Comment: My solution below should work in 05 and later.

Answer (score 55):

Dynamic SQL:

```
select 'set identity_insert ['+s.name+'].['+o.name+'] off'
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id=o.schema_id
where o.[type]='U'
and exists(select 1 from sys.columns where object_id=o.object_id and is_identity=1)
```

Then copy & paste the resulting SQL into another query window and run

Comment: I want to have this for my bulk db insert from my code. Can you suggest something how to achieve that in jpa?

Comment: This query is great, because it checks which tables have identity enabled and then generates the `off` script for that. When you want to enable it again you just change the `off` in the query to `on`

Answer (score 20):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="SET IDENTITY_INSERT ? OFF"
```

Comment: I like this a lot... except, not every table in this db has an identity field, so this fails. Otherwise I suspect it would be perfect.

Comment: At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx#feedback

Comment: @qub1n The OP didn't ask to set the property to ON.

Comment: I know it is not tasked, but I hope it will be useful information for those who are looking for SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON like me.

Answer (score 9):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="PRINT '?'; SET IDENTITY_INSERT ? OFF",
@whereand = ' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = o.id  AND is_identity = 1)'
```

Building on Lynn's answer, in case you're too lazy to perform this in more than one step - this should run on all tables where there is an identity column.

Caveat is only tested in 2012 and *sp_MSforeachtable* is of course entirely unsupported...

Answer (score 4):

Building on @KevD's answer - It was working fine for disabling but here is more for enabling as well.

To disable all identity inserts where they need to be disabled, use -

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="PRINT '?'; SET IDENTITY_INSERT ? OFF",
@whereand = ' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = o.id  
AND is_identity = 1) and o.type = ''U'''
```

To enable all identity inserts where they need to be enabled, use -

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="PRINT '?'; SET IDENTITY_INSERT ? ON",
@whereand = ' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = o.id  
AND is_identity = 1) and o.type = ''U'''
```

Tested on Sql server 2014 and 2016

Comment: Turning ON fails if it's already on, exiting the EXEC. Is there a way to test the bit first?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I'd rather not use undocumented stored procedures in production. To automate this I built on to @John Dewey's answer and put it into a cursor. This iterates over 699 tables in 407 ms.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500) -- SQL command to execute

DECLARE sql_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 'SET identity_insert ['+s.name+'].['+o.name+'] OFF'
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id=o.schema_id
WHERE o.[type]='U'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=o.object_id AND is_identity=1)

OPEN sql_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql  --> Comment this out to test
        -- PRINT @sql   --> Uncomment to test or if logging is desired
        FETCH NEXT FROM sql_cursor INTO @sql
    END

CLOSE sql_cursor
DEALLOCATE sql_cursor
```

If you are against cursors, it could also be easily transformed into a while loop.