# SQL Server generated bug data script how not to set the IDENTITY in the insert statements?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to generate a SQL script (big one) to update an Azure SQL database. The problem is that the script is generated with `IDENTITY` on and the insert statements are exported with the ID column which as result cause this error :

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_Name'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

My question is how to generate the script right that is will not use IDENTITY on and the insert?

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT <<table_name>> ON; at the places where you want to insert the identity yourself. After finished that one, SET IDENTITY_INSERT <<table_name>> OFF;

Comment: well i have allot of tables and the script is big something like 300 mega 
is it safe to manually turn off all SET IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF ?

Comment: Turn off Identity Insert for all tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116759/set-identity-insert-off-for-all-tables

Comment: i did changed it to off

Answer (score 1):

Quick example of using `set identity_insert` here: http://rextester.com/NGN7719

When using the **generate scripts task** in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) to generate scripts with data, `set identity_insert` statements will be included for tables that have an identity column.

In the object explorer: Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> [All Tables *or* selected tables] -> Advanced -> [Schema with Data *or* Data]

- If the table to script data from **does not** have a column with the identity property, it will not generate the `set identity_insert` statements.
- If the table to script data from **does** have a column with the identity property, it will generate the `set identity_insert` statements.

Tested & Confirmed using SSMS 208 & SSMS 2012

In the OP's situation, I'm guessing the origin table did not have the identity property set for `my_table_id` in the source table, but the identity property was set for `my_table_id` in the destination table.

To get the desired output, change the table to script data from to have `my_table_id` to have the identity property.

This article explains in depth the steps to do this (without using the designer in SSMS): [Add or drop identity property for an existing SQL Server column - Greg Robidoux](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/)

- Create a new column with the identity property
- Transfer the data from the existing id column to the new column
- Drop the existing id column.
- Rename the new column to the original column name

---

This is the example code used in the rextester example above.

```
create table table_w_identity (
    IdentityColumn int identity (1,1)
  , OtherColumn nvarchar(128)
  , constraint pk_table_w_identity primary key clustered (IdentityColumn asc)
  , constraint uc_table_w_identity_OtherColumn unique (OtherColumn)
  );

set identity_insert dbo.table_w_identity on;
  insert into dbo.table_w_identity (IdentityColumn, OtherColumn)
    values (1, 'identity_insert is on');
    /* succeeds */

set identity_insert dbo.table_w_identity off;
  insert into dbo.table_w_identity (OtherColumn)
    values ('identity_insert is off');
    /* succeeds */
```

The following two statements fail:

```
set identity_insert dbo.table_w_identity off;
  insert into dbo.table_w_identity (IdentityColumn, OtherColumn)
    values (3, 'identity_insert is off, this fails because identitycolumn is trying to be inserted');
    /* fails */
```

> Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table_w_identity' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

```
set identity_insert dbo.table_w_identity on;
  insert into dbo.table_w_identity (OtherColumn)
    values ('identity_insert is on, this fails b/c identitycolumn is not being inserted');
    /* fails */
```

> Error: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'table_w_identity' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

This is the output when I generate the script from SSMS for data only for the example table used in the above rextester:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table_w_identity] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[table_w_identity] ([IdentityColumn], [OtherColumn]) VALUES (2, N'identity_insert is off')
INSERT [dbo].[table_w_identity] ([IdentityColumn], [OtherColumn]) VALUES (1, N'identity_insert is on')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table_w_identity] OFF
```

Documentation:
- [`set identity_insert` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post now, but IMO the only provided answer does not address the issue, which is that exporting / importing a database using the Generate Scripts is flaky at best.

I have several times used the wizard to generate the scripts then used them in a blank database and had exactly this error, when really there should have been no reason for any errors at all.

The best process is:

1. Generate Schema Only and create the database first
2. Disable all constraints: `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'`
3. Generate the data, **BUT**, and here is the key thing, don't try to do everything at once. Do it a table at a time, or in batches of smaller tables.
4. On any error, truncate all tables in the erroring batch, and try to fix the error.
5. If every table is imported successfully, re-enable constraints: `exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'`

I don't know why, but both SSMS and sqlcmd (I'm on 2008 r2) just seem to have problems running large scripts. My last failure was `no value provided for required parameter` on a row that was absolutely fine; when run as a smaller batch it worked without a problem.

The OP's error is caused by the fact that if a spurious error like the above happens, then the script ends up in an incorrect state, and the built-in `set identity_insert on` statements fail to work.

N.B. The Generate Scripts command has an option for "one file per object" which is probably a good way to go as well.

Hope this helps someone!