# How to set 'Enable identity insert' for all the tables at once during importing data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to copy a database from a remote server. I don't have access to its backups or file system. My destination database on my dev machine needs to get all the data plus the same tables structures including primary keys with identity settings and the rest of the constraints.

The Import/Export facility has the option to set the identity insert as shown below but I have to do this manually per table. I have over 300 tables to copy and most of them have identity primary keys. This is going to be very painful process doing the copy multiple times.

Is there a way to set this identity insert setting all at once for all the tables? Or some other reliable way of copying databases in such a setup? 
I am using SSMS 7.3 against SQL Server 2014.

[image]

Comment: Is all the tables in your database has an identity column? or just some?

Comment: Mybe you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680215/6426692) and try to revers it :)

Comment: You cannot do this - `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` can **only** be on for **ONE TABLE** at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Toad](https://www.quest.com/toad) to do a data compare and it generated insert statements for the data. Each insert group per table was wrapped between setting the IDENTITY_INSERT ON then OFF. Toad is a commercial product but have a trial period.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want by creating the import package using OLE DB source/destination components with the default identity insert. Save it to a package file instead of executing immediately. Open the package source in a text editor and change the `FastLoadKeepIdentity` property for the destination tables with identity columns.

Below is an xml fragment of the package source that needs to be changed for each table. Below is the property that needs to be changed:

```
            <property
              dataType="System.Boolean"
              description="Indicates whether the values supplied for identity columns will be copied to the destination. If false, values for identity columns will be auto-generated at the destination. Applies only if fast load is turned on."
              name="FastLoadKeepIdentity">true</property>
```

Run the modified package using the `dtexec.exe` command-line utility or the `dtexecui.exe` graphical tool. That will allow you to easily repeat the copy without going through the import/export wizard again.